# What is the name of the service called to drive one's car home after drinking?

Tags: words

Someone else drives the car for the person who has been drinking. I spelled the word "daiko" but came up with radish.

Comment: Try daikou/代行...

Comment: @Shoko, I was able to translate as "acting as an agent".

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but radish should be 大根 (daikon) though.

Comment: that was my same mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is commonly called 「運転代行{うんてんだいこう}」 (= "chauffeur service").  When it is clear from the context what type of service one is talking about, the shortened form 「代行」 may be used.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%81%8B%E8%BB%A2%E4%BB%A3%E8%A1%8C

The TV commercial below might seem strange if one is not familiar with this service or if one is from a country where it is just normal to drive to and from bars.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkkf8S0QtZM

Comment: Sorry. I am also looking for a word for one (A) taking a test for another one (B) on B's behalf. Is it ok to call A 試験代行?

Comment: ^ それはもしかして「替え玉受験」（A =「替え玉」）・・・？